# Error for c++ example

Tags: c++, loops, casting

I want to input alphabet to binary code, and output the alphabet from generated binary code.
Example

```
1      --> a
01     --> b
001    --> c
0001   --> d
00001  --> e
000001 --> f

a => 1
b => 01
c => 001
d => 0001
e => 00001
```

-------------Encode.cpp--------------------

```
#include "Encode.h"


Encode::Encode()
{
}


Encode::~Encode()
{
}

void Encode::inputWord() 
{
    cout << "Input word: ";
    cin.getline(word, 255);
    return;
}// User input a word

char * Encode::getBuf(void)
{
    return buffer;
}// return buffer to Decode::setBuf(char* buf)

void Encode::printEncResult()
{
    int size = strlen(word);
    int buffersize = 0;
    cout << "Encoding result" << endl; // print similar binary

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'z')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                cout<<buffer[buffersize++];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int len = (int)word[i] - (int)'a';
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                cout<<buffer[buffersize++];
            }
            cout << buffer[buffersize++];
        }
    }   
}// output similar binary

int Encode::encodeWord(void)
{
    int buffersize = 0;
    int size = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'z')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                buffer[buffersize++] = '0';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int len = (int)word[i] - (int)'a';
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
            buffer[buffersize++] = '0';
            }

            buffer[buffersize++] = '1';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}// change word to similar binary
```

--------Decode.cpp-------------

```
#include "Decode.h"


Decode::Decode()
{
}


Decode::~Decode()
{
}

void Decode::setBuf(char * buf)
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;

    while (*(buf + i) == '1' || *(buf + i) == '0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    size = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = buf[i];
    }
    return;
}// set buffer from Encode::getBuf(void)

void Decode::printWord() // print similar binary
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int check = 1;
    while (check)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 'a' && (int)word[i] <= 'z')
        {
            i++;
            size = i;
        }
        else
            check = 0;
    }

    cout << "Decoding result" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 'a' && (int)word[i] <= 'z') // **this part is also strange** I can not shoten the code.
            cout<<word[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int Decode::decodebin(vector<char> buffer)
{
    int buffersize = 0;
    int check = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char printval = 'a';

    while (buffer[i] == '1' || buffer[i] == '0')
    {
    i++;
    }
    size = i;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) // nested loop does not work. I want save words in order
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == '0')
                ++printval;
            else
            {
                word[j] = printval; // In this part, word[0] does not have any value.
                printval = 'a';
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

In this code, I want save values in order, but word[0] does not have any value. Moreover, If I input 'bb' then, 'bbbb' saved ins `word` array.

Comment: Mathematically 1 == 01 == 001 are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: By binary, you mean unary? You shouldn't use "magic numbers" like 97 and 122. Instead, just use their character equivalent like `'A'`.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to find the size of an array by iterating through it until you reach an invalid value. Note that reading past the end of an array generates undefined behavior, and it wouldn't be suprizing if your program crashes or gets the wrong size. Instead, pass the size to the function or use standard library containers like `std::vector` that actually keeps track of their own size.

Comment: I know it is not mathematically right. It is my intention.@Slava

Comment: No, i did not mean unary. It has no relation with any number system. I just want to exchange numbers to similar binary code following my rules.
I will follow your advise(std::vector)-@Fei Xiang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems and consideration you need to take care of:

1. as Fei Xiang said in the comments don't use magic numbers, use characters since you have a character array.
2. int `printWord` function you actually get the word and print the same word, there is no conversion as your problem statement. your didn't take `buffer` into account.
3. you are using some data validation to get your array size, this could end up a disaster(UB). you need to pass your array size to your function or use `std::vector`(*Recommended*).
4. in this statement `if ((int)word[i] >= 97 || (int)word[i] <= 122)` as I said don't use magic number and `||` should be change to `&&` otherwise you end up in an infinity loop.

Anyway by keeping your approach(using array) and function signature here's what you can do :

```
int Decode::decodebin(void)
{
    int buffersize = 0;
    int check = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char printval = 'a';
    while(buffer[i] == '1' || buffer[i] == '0')
    {
        i++;
        size = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == '0')
            ++printval;
        else
        {
            cout << printval;
            printval = 'a';
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

void Decode::printWord()
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int check = 1;
    while(check)
    {
        if(word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
        {
            i++;
            size = i;
        }
        else
            check = 0;
    }
    cout << "Decoding result" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int distance = word[i] - 'a';
        for(int j = 0; j < distance; ++j)
            cout << '0';
        cout << '1';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON OP REQUIREMENT IN COMMENTS:**

using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you can implement your needs like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Decode
{
public:
    void decodebin(std::vector<char> buffer)
    {
        char printval = 'a';
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
        {
            if(buffer[i] == '0')
                ++printval;
            else
            {
                word.push_back(printval);
                printval = 'a';
            }
        }
    }

    void printWord(void)
    {
        for(auto iter = word.begin(); iter != word.end(); ++iter)
            std::cout << *iter;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<char> word;
};

int main()
{
    Decode decoder;
    std::vector<char> buffer = {'0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'};
    decoder.decodebin(buffer);
    decoder.printWord();
    return 0;
}
```

Here `decodebin` stores the given input into `word` member variable of `Decode` class. Then `printWord` function print `word` values on the screen.

`std::vector` has all the power of C-style array and it's nicer and easier to use. You can retrieve it's size whenever you want and you don't have to worry about the memory it's allocating.

Comment: I used your advise. It works but can not get exactly what i want.
Can I ask you some more questions? - @Hamed

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am making a program that input a word then, change to similar binary code and change similar binary to the same word.
I've used the code you've changed, and what I want to do is change the word int decodebin(void) and then store the values in order from word 0 to word[] array. However, I think that it is necessary to change the loop according to the length of the input word. - @Hamed

Comment: Hello Hamed, I uploaded a new question based on your code. Could you check that question please? - @Hamed

Comment: Sorry Hamed, I did it because I was not familiar with stackoverflow. I have modified the code in this article so coule you take a look? - @Hamed

Comment: @Aiden Your `decodebin` function is not the same as the function I posted as answer, Why you are using nested loop in it?

Comment: I tested your code. It works very well, but I want 2 things.
First : In `decodebin`, i want save values in `word` array.
Second : In `printWord`, output the `word` array.
So i used nested loop to save values in `word` array.
@Hamed

Comment: @Aiden I see, are you allowed to use `std::vector`?

Comment: I never used `std::vector`. I will use it right now. - @Hamed

Comment: @Aiden OK I'll show you the way, give me a moment then I will notify you to check answer update.

Comment: Umm.. I appreciate for your help Hamed. I tested it and it fits to my intention. But there are some problems.
**First** : i have `setBuf(char* buf)` method in `Decode` class. it gets similar binary and save into `buffer[i]`.
**Second** : `setBuf` get `char* buf` from `Encode`class

**I will upload my full code of Decode and Encode**

Comment: @Aiden that would be the whole code review and we are not allowed to do this here and if you want you can take your code to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you want to benefit from `std::vector` in your project you need to learn more about it but I think this question is answered and more update would not be appropriate. At the end, please consider marking it as answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate to you Hamed. I learned a lot from you. As your advise, i will upload question to `code riview`

Comment: @Aiden You are welcome. Again `std::vector` is great. learn to use it. C-style arrays stink.